# Can I use both Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Native for UI on the same project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am currently new to Xamarin. I have learned to develop both on Xamarin.Android - Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms. My background comes from native Android apps (Java) and iOS apps(Swift). My question is can I use Xamarin.Forms for basic UI and at the same time Xamarin.Native for more complicated UI on the same project? More specific can I combine all the Xamarin technologies on UI perspective on the same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. You need to create standard Xamarin.iOS + Xamarin.Android projects and add to them Xamarin.Forms NuGet. You can add Xamarin.Forms pages in the shared project, create those classes in the native projects and transform them to `UIViewController` or `Fragment`. More here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-forms/

Just to note that this isn't in any kind of preview.

Answer (score 6):

> More specific can I combine all the Xamarin technologies on UI perspective on the same project?

Yes, but those features are currently in a preview state, buyer beware ;-)

- Embedding Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Native
- https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-in-xamarin-native/

`Xamarin.Forms` **3.0** of Embedding is currently in preview and is available via a custom Nuget feed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it by using [custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

From a personal point of view, if you find yourself in the need of having a very customised UI, and so use a lot of renderers, I'd completely skip Xamarin Forms. It is very good for prototyping and simple apps, otherwise it is not so easy to deal with the additional complexity of using custom renderers.

Comment: Yeah I agree I have just learnt about custom platform renderers on Xamarin University, it seems they are doing the work but a lot of them can cause problems in code maintenance and of course you can lose the advantages of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: I disagree with this, at least the skipping part. Using a custom renderer just means you have to implement said stuff platform-dependently, so you lose the advantage of Xamarin.Forms, that is true. But that won't make it a worse choice, just the same as coding said part in a true-native way. But you don't always have to do this. My experience is if you truly learn how to harness the abilities that Effects, Behaviors, DependencyService and CustomRenderers provide you (for me really understanding these concepts took a lot of time), Xamarin.Forms can be really powerful for business applications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, easily. Use Xamarin native MVVMCross for your application architecture, then you can use custom presenters to present either a native view, or a Xamarin.Forms view. It's extremely flexible, easy to use, and beautiful.

Check out this video by Xamarin MVP Martijn van Dijk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0VW11yv2AI